# Shell syntax IFS

Tags: bash, shell, ifs

I'm trying to run a simple shell script example:

```
STR="qwe;ert;rty;tii"
IFS=';' read -r NAMES <<< "$STR"
```

This is giving me the following error message:

```
syntax error: got <&, expecting Word
```

I'm not exactly sure why this isn't working. I thought the syntax I used was 
correct and I tried comparing to other examples and I saw the syntax was almost
identical.

Any feedback would help

Thanks

Comment: not addressing your issue but you may want to use `-a` option.

Comment: There *is* no `<&` is your code. Please make sure that your snippet *actually reproduces your problem* before asking a question.

Comment: ...btw, we had this **exact** question posted, and deleted, a few days ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38667961/shell-script-issue

Comment: I am simply copy pasting the error message I got

Comment: Yes, but the question is *what code you're getting the error message from*. Can you get the error from a script with those exact two lines **and absolutely nothing else**? Have you tested that that's true? If so, how are you invoking the script? `sh yourscript`? `bash yourscript`? `ksh yourscript`? ...?

Comment: I literally wrote only those 2 lines and nothing else. Thats the whole script on bash

Comment: Again, did you put them in a file? How are you running the file?

Comment: I open bash than type in the script which only contains those 2 lines for example open bash go to directory and type in myscript.sh

Comment: so you're running this interactively, not as a script?

Comment: ...I ask in part because there's a lot more that goes on in an interactive environment than when running a script -- you can have pre-prompt commands etc.

Comment: Yes I know that but I was getting an error with this syntax for some reason so I made something really simple just to isolate and see what was wrong

Comment: What's your operating system and exact shell version? Is this "Git Bash" or some other MSYS-based Windows build? What does `echo "$BASH_VERSION"` emit? If you save this script to a file, and run `bash -x YourFileNameHere`, what gets emitted?

Comment: ...as another aside, it's best practice to avoid all-uppercase variable names, which are used by variables with meaning to the shell and operating system. We get too many questions from folks who used `PATH` as a name for one of their own variables and then wonder why nothing else works; using `path` (`str`, `names`, etc) instead avoids collisions.

Comment: echo $BASH_VERSION gives 9.4.1 build 3049 and when I do bash -x filename I get the output of STR=qwe;ert;rty;tii followed by syntax error <&, expecting word

Comment: `9.4.1` isn't a version of bash that exists -- the most recent release series is 4.3.x as of this writing. Presumably you're using something which isn't, well, *actually bash*.

Comment: MKS bash would that make a difference in the syntax and give errors like this?

Comment: Yes, that would make a difference. MKS bash isn't really bash. You haven't heard the story about MKS and David Korn, have you?

Comment: ...see question #5 at https://slashdot.org/story/01/02/06/2030205/david-korn-tells-all (re: MKS's attempt at a Korn shell).

Comment: OH well that is funny, and also frustrating since I guess the syntax was right but just didn't work on MKS. Thank you

Comment: well, I wouldn't quite say right -- it wouldn't do what you're trying to do in real bash, but it also wouldn't give this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is MKS bash, not GNU bash. It's not really bash, and doesn't support the genuine shell's syntax.

There are perfectly good (...well, reasonably adequate) builds of GNU bash for Windows. Use them.

---

Particularly, in real bash, to split a semicolon-separated string into an array of names:

```
str='qwe;ert;rty;tii'
IFS=';' read -r -a names <<<"$str"
```

...which you can then verify with

```
declare -p names
```

or emit one-to-a-line with

```
printf '%s\n' "${names[@]}"
```